# Rubik's Cube Riddle

Tags: probability, puzzle

When I was toying around with a [Rubik's cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube), I got a inspiration for a Maths puzzle, and I find it extremely difficult to answer. This riddle was all by me.

Imagine you are blindfolded and a randomly oriented Rubik's cube is placed in front of you by one of the hosts of this riddle. Your task is to guess on which face the white center is, but you only have 4 guesses. Is it possible to win every time? The host can also hear in your strategy and try their best to thwart you.

I tried to come up with strategies to solve this, and all failed, but I cannot yet prove this is impossible. If it is, I'll try to soften the riddle a bit. The variation is that after your first failed guess, the host points out a face that doesn't have a yellow center other than the one you picked. If that's still impossible, the host will point to another face that doesn't have a yellow center.

Comment: When you say "points out a face that is not yellow", you mean any face or the face you made the guess for?

Comment: Huh?  What's this have to do with "prison"?  "Guess where the white face is..."  Is the cube solved?  If so, what does this have to do with Rubik at all??  If not, how do you define "white face"?  There are six sides and you get to guess four.  And sooo.....

Comment: I am also assuming here, one is not allowed to tamper with the Rubix Cube,.i.e., modify its orientation. Is that true?

Comment: What does "$1$ million dollars" have to do with anything?  What does it mean that a host "hears my strategy"????   Why would I tell her anything?  Please re-write this question to pare it down to its essence.  It shows courtesy to readers and might help you solve it on your own.

Comment: "The host will point to a face that is not white" is a different face from the previous two?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The puzzle obviously isn't solvable without having the million dollar prize as an incentive.

Comment: This problem is a mess... such a mess... and the newbie OP refuses to let others fix it.  The question should be closed.

Comment: I hope you all understand that this is purely for fun. I enjoy doing maths a whole lot and this puzzle is very interesting in my opinion. Thanks for your help.

Comment: All right, let's stick to constructive feedback.

Comment: I think it is important to note that in a Rubik's Cube, white is always opposite yellow, red opposite orange, and blue opposite to green. 
4 guesses should do it every time if after each guess you are told the colour of the centre you guessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With 4 guesses and no feedbacks, the chances are as good as a random guess. Only 6 guesses are a sure way.
2. With 4 guesses and feedback over yellow on first attempt, there are 2 cases:

- If that face is not white, the rest of the 3 guesses can be made on each of remaining faces.
- If that face is white, you will need 5 guesses.

So this situation would still need 5 guesses.

3. Proceeding similarly for 4 guesses and feedback over yellow on 2 faces, you should be able to find that 4 guesses are sufficient.